# How to Graph in R with dates and timestamps

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, timestamp

I have the current datagram in R:

```
timestamp Name FP Date   
1500485400000,Unknown,0.04,Jul 19,2017 2:25:08 PM  
1500486300000,Unknown,0.06,Jul 19,2017 2:25:08 PM  
1500494400000,Unknown,0.17,Jul 19,2017 4:24:38 PM  
1500495300000,Unknown,0.14,Jul 19,2017 4:24:38 PM  
1500498000000,Unknown,0.12,Jul 19,2017 5:01:48 PM  
1500500700000,Unknown,0.12,Jul 19,2017 6:15:11 PM  
1500501600000,Unknown,0.11,Jul 19,2017 6:15:11 PM  
1500502500000,Unknown,0.07,Jul 19,2017 6:15:11 PM
```

What I would like to do is a `ggplot` of this data frame where its grouped by hour and these hours are plotted according to the timestamp.
SO the x axis would be the FP and the y axis would be the dates/hour and in the order of the timestamp. Or another way to look at it is graphing it in the order it appears in the table.
example

[image]

Comment: You'll get more responses if you include a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please clarify your post...what is on x-axis? `timestamp`? `Date`? Or `FP`? On y-axis? `FP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add a reorder to the ggplot therefore u need to add a column in the datagram from 1-15 to make it reorder by the row. like this:

```
c=nrow(databyname)  
databyname$rowid<- 1:c
```

then u plot it using this

```
ggplot(databyname, aes(x =reorder(databyname$`Date and Timestamp`,databyname$rowid), y = databyname$Total_Frames,group=1)) +
  geom_point()+ geom_line()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ggtitle(name2)+
  xlab('Date and Timestamp')+ylab('Total Frames')+geom_line()
```